# How to pass datetime2(0) in wcf uri template?

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, datetime, datetime2

İ want pass some values also include datetime's. I am trying this way but i am getting this error "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime2."

This is my function;

```
public string InsertRezervation(int GarageId, int MemberId, string StartDate, string EndDate, bool isFinish)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = null;
            SqlCommand command = null;
            int rowsAffected = 0;

            string format = "yyyyMMdd";
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2014, 12, 18);
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2014, 12, 25);
            if (StartDate != null && EndDate != null)
            {
                startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
            connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand("Parking.Rezervation", connection);
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@PGarageId", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = GarageId;
            command.Parameters.Add("@PMemberId", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = MemberId;
            command.Parameters.Add("@PStartDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = startDate;
            command.Parameters.Add("@PEndDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = endDate;
            command.Parameters.Add("@PIsFinish", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = isFinish;
            command.CommandText = "Parking.Rezervation";
            rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", rowsAffected.ToString());

        }
```

And this is interface;

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        UriTemplate = "/InsertRezervation?GarageId={GarageId}&MemberId={MemberId}&StartDate={StartDate}&EndDate={EndDate}&isFinish={isFinish}")]
        string InsertRezervation(int GarageId, int MemberId, string StartDate, string EndDate, bool isFinish);
```

How can i fix this problem.

Comment: Could you add the code of the stored procedure?. You pass paramenters of NVARCHAR type and if the stored procedure expects different types then you get the error.

Comment: Just guessing, but most likely you intended to pass 'startDate' and 'endDate' as datetime2 parameters - but you are actually passing them as NVarChar types: 'command.Parameters.Add("@PStartDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = startDate;'. I suggest changing NVarChar to DateTime2 there ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your `DateTime` values with `SqlDbType.NVarChar` type. Change them to `SqlDbType.DateTime2` like;

```
command.Parameters.Add("@PStartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = startDate;
command.Parameters.Add("@PEndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = endDate;
```

Also change for `GarageId` and `MemberId` to `SqlDbType.Int` and for `isFinish` to `SqlDbType.Bit` if they fits your column types. Don't use `NVarChar` for all of them.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

Comment: @mesopotamia Glad to help.